# How come my Python code doesn't work?

Tags: python, django, file, rabbitmq, celery

from celery.decorators import task

```
from celery.decorators import task
@task()
def add(x, y):
    r = open("./abc.txt","w")
    r.write("sdf")
    r.close()
    return x + y
```

That's my tasks.py file.

```
>>> import tasks
>>> r = tasks.add.delay(3,5)
>>> r.result
8
```

As you can see, the function works. However, **the file does not create**.
Why?

I've tried changing multiple file paths, due to possible permission issues. but no luck.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What if you use an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file was not being written, you would get an exception, so the function cannot possibly complete.

Since the function is returning 8, it follows that the file is being written somewhere.

Perhaps the file is written in a different directory to the one you are expecting

The only other possibility I can think of is that the add function that is being run is not the one that you have shown here

Comment: You can use `import os; os.getcwd()` to find out what directory Python thinks `.` refers to. This is often set to something very inconvenient; if I start up Python from my Start menu, it will be `C:\\Windows\\system32` ! If I start it from a command window, it will be whatever the path was in the command window when I started up Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're running this by importing a module. The `.` in the file path is relative to where the module lives, not your current working directory. Try giving it a full path name.

If that doesn't work, show us exactly where you're running the script from and an `ls -la` on that directory. And if that still doesn't show anything abnormal. Do a

`find / -name abc.txt`

Answer (score 1):

1. The working directory may not be the one you expect.
2. The task may be done on another host, if you use multiple hosts.